# Placing and rotating svg elements along a path with Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have been trying out snap.svg and I'm new to svg manipulation in javascript so bear with me :)

I have created a path that I'm placing other shapes along. The placing works fine but I'd like the shapes that I place to always point straight out, getting the angle of the object to align with whatever route the path takes. Think of this as placing text along a svg path, getting each character to bend with the path, facing outwards or inwards.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please post your current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Snaps getPointAtLength() method ([docs](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.getPointAtLength)) you will find included in the return object is 'alpha'.

Alpha varies as the path does, so you can just set your element to rotate at the value of the returned alpha (you may need to offset it by 90 degrees or something).

So in totally untested code it would look something like...

```
 myPoint = myShape.getPointAtLength( lengthSoFarInPath ) 
 myShape.transform('t' + myPoint.x + ',' + myPoint.y + 'r' + myPoint.alpha)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works very well for getting the right rotation. I'm not sure how to work with the offset, now my object rotates the way I want, but it position is offset from the path at various distances when getting the .getPointAtLength(). Do you have any suggestion about this?

Comment: If there is an offset of distance, you can compensate by adding an offset to myPoint.x/y eg 20 and -10 to position it, and if necessary an offset for the alpha.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick replies, you have really been a great help. I have played around with offsets, but can't seem to wrap my head around how to calculate them. I made a little fiddle with my experimentations http://jsfiddle.net/spellfork/9Lxaqjmc/

If you have the time, maybe you could look at that. I want my triangle shape to slide alog the path and always point outwards, but still touching its base to the path-line.

Comment: This starts to get fiddlier as the point you want to pivot your object around isn't in the centre. So you may need to adjust your original triangle points to be further along the x,y coordinates.There are ways to transform the path, like Snap.path.map, but thats probably a separate question and more involved. Try adjusting your triangle first to have different coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'll try adjust the coordinates of the triangle. I had an idea that invloved grouping my triangle with another, larger object with the triangle base aligned to that objects center point. I'll try it.